# Filling a vector of unique_ptr with multiple threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, unique-ptr

I have a class that, given a device ID, initializes that device. The destructor of the class spools down the device again.

As I have a multiple of these devices connected to my system, I wrote an enumerator class that initializes each connected device. As the destructor of `device` releases the device's resources, I used `unique_ptr< device >` so there is no unintentional copying / deleting of `device` objects.

```
struct device_id {
    // information to identify device
}

class device {
    public:
        device( device_id const & id ) {
            // initialize device
        }

        void act() {
            // use the device
        }

        ~device() {
            // spool down device
        }
};

class device_enumerator {
    public:
        device_enumerator( std::vector< device_id > const & ids ) {
            for ( auto const & id : ids ) {
                devices.push_back( std::unique_ptr< device >( new device( id ) ) );
            }
        }

        typedef std::vector< std::unique_ptr< device > > device_vector;

        device_vector::iterator begin() { return devices.begin(); }
        device_vector::iterator end() { return devices.end(); }

    private:
        device_vector devices;
};
```

As each device takes some time to spool up, initializing all devices in sequence is a lengthy process. So I would like to parallelize the device intitialization (since the device constructor basically sits idle until the device signals back).

But -- this being the first time I attempt to work with `<thread>` -- I cannot wrap my head around how I would go about retrieving a `std::unique_ptr< device >` from a `std::thread` for each device, and then join the threads again, with any kind of elegance. (If `std::thread` is indeed the right thing to use here...)

**How can I parallelize this:**

```
for ( auto const & id : ids ) {
    devices.push_back( std::unique_ptr< device >( new device( id ) ) );
}
```

Comment: It's probably easier to move-assign rather than push back because you would get rid of the need to synchronize the concurrent modification of the vector. With assignment, it's as easy as `#pragma omp parallel for`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since initializing each device is independent task, so std::async makes more sense here and sample code to achieve this is as follows :

```
void init(std::unique_ptr<device>& p)
{
  p.reset(new device(device_id())); //time consuming operation

}
int main() {
  //8 number of elements in vector are for demo purpose only
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<device>> vecOfDevices(8); 
  std::vector<std::future<void>> vecOfFutures(8);
  int index = 0;
  for(auto& elem:vecOfDevices)
  {
    //async launch policy will construct each in seperate thread
    vecOfFutures[index] = std::async(std::launch::async,init,std::ref(vecOfDevices[index]));
    index++;
  }
  //Do some other operations here
  for(auto& elem:vecOfFutures)
  {
    elem.wait(); //wait so that all devices got initialized
  }
  //start using your devices from here
  vecOfDevices[0]->act();  
  return 0;
}
```